# Get name of the field by value

Tags: json, bash, select, jq

Hello i have the current json

```
[
  {
    "name": "2020-11-02-160548",
    "value": "ami-asd637ccb094d"
  }
]
```

I want to extract the name of the field name: when i know the value: ami-asd637ccb094d. I`m trying to do it with jq . The expected result is 2020-11-02-160548. Any help?

Answer (score 1):

```
.[] | select(.value=="ami-asd637ccb094d") | .name
```

https://jqplay.org/s/kvahxrql43

Answer (score -1):

Found the solution

```
jq '.[] | select(.value=="ami-0f5c399636ccb094d") | .name?' | tr -d '""' file.json
```

Comment: It does not work this way. First of all, `file.json` needs to be passed as argument to `jq`; as it is now it is an argument of `file.json` (that does not expect an extra argument for `-d`) and `jq` is waiting for its input from `stdin`. Either put `file.json` before `| tr` or put `cat file.json | ` in front of `jq`. `tr` is not needed, `jq -r` displays the raw output (i.e. not encoded as JSON), therefore without the surrounding quotes you want to remove using `tr`.

Comment: For robustness and efficiency, use the jq command-line option `-r` instead of `tr`.